# Getting an Index/Match with a single criteria to sum its results

Tags: indexing, sum, match

I am using an INDEX/MATCH to locate a facility number, then go to the appropriate column and return the first non-blank answer it receives. this is great. However, I can't figure out how to add a SUM function to this, so it will add all of the index match results, and not just stop at the first one it finds. I'd like to only use a formula, not VB. This is what my array currently looks like.

=INDEX(INDIRECT("$H"&(MATCH(M45,$B:$B,0))&":$H$10000"),MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(INDIRECT("$H"&(MATCH(M45,$B:$B,0))&":$H$10000")), 0))